# How to access a collection of SseEmitters located inside a @Service Class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

The `sses` Map has been moved from MessageController class to a class annotated with @Service `MessageTemplate.class` . Now we need a way to add `SseEmitter` instances (created inside `openConn()`) to the sses map inside MessageTemplate class.

Map may not be the best choice here, if so, what other cache alternatives available because I need a away to send messages back to individual clients?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class MessageController{
@Autowired MessageOperations mesgOps;

   //Moved to MessageTemplate
   Map<String, SseEmitter> sses = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @GetMapping(value = "/conn/{username}")
    public SseEmitter openConn(@PathVariable("username") String username){
        SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter(3600000L);
        sses.put(username, sseEmitter);
        return sseEmitter;
    }


@Service 
public class MessageTemplate implements MessageOperations{
//The above map now resides here.
Map<String, SseEmitter> sses = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
..
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, all the presented abstraction in the question are “custom” (the code that was written in your organization) and do not belong to spring ecosystem by themselves, I see the following:

1. A `MessageTemplate` is a singleton-scoped bean driven by spring
2. The controller is also a singleton bean.
3. `MessageOperations` interface is your custom interface that you’re using for injection.

In this case the obvious change would be:

```
interface MessageOperations {
    SseEmitter associateSseEmitterWithUser(String userName); 
}

@Service
public class MessageTemplate implements MessageOperations {
      private Map<String, SseEmitter> sses = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

      // other existing code you might already have
     
      public SseEmitter associateSseEmitterWithUser(String username) {
            SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter(3600000L);
            sses.put(username, sseEmitter);
            return sseEmitter;
      }
}

@Controller 
@RequestMapping(value = “/“)
public class MessageController {
     @Autowired MessageOperations mesgOps;
     
     @GetMapping(value=“/conn/{username})
     public SseEmitter openConn(@PathVariable(“username”) String   username) {
          return mesgOps.associateSseEmitterWithUser(username); 
     }  
}
```

Comment: Hah. You used a Setter. Just thought there maybe a more elegant solution to this. Nvm

Comment: Well, actually I'm not sure how you can do better than that, assuming that the concurrent hash map has become a private data field and you need to add some data to it from the outside. So obviously some method has to be called on the object that contains the private data structure - what can be easier than the direct method invocation? Anyway, could you describe what "feels" more elegant to You and what do You think is wrong with the presented approach, so that our colleagues and I could suggest (hopefully better) alternatives?